# Inconvertible type cannot cast android.view.view to javafx.scene.web.webview

Tags: java, android

i want to show my post in webview but i fatch error of **"Inconvertible type cannot cast android.view.view to javafx.scene.web.webview"** in android studio.
    how can i solve it please help me.

**WPPostDetails.java**

```
package com.ejobbox.ejobbox;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class WPPostDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView title;
    WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_postdetails);
        title=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.postwebview);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("itemPosition");

        //title.setText(MainActivity.mListPost.get(position).getTitle().getRendered());
        Log.e("WpPostDetails","title is"+MainActivity.mListPost.get(position).getTitle().getRendered());

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You import a wrong `WebView` class. Remove `import javafx.scene.web.WebView;` and add `import android.webkit.WebView`

Answer (score 0):

Import 
    android.webkit.WebView instead of
    javafx.scene.web.WebView;